# Automate MaxMind login and DB download

Tags: php, maxmind

I'm trying to use PHP CURL to login to the MaxMind account and download a specific file, I can't even get the login part to work, the following returns "false":

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.maxmind.com/en/account');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I would suggest that you will need to use more options in your curl request - such as useragent, cookies and, because it's ssl, options for ssl - such as using a valid cacert.pem file ( for cainfo ) etc - and because the fields are named `login` and `password` you should probably use `http_build_query` on an array to simulate the fields being submitted via post - which is another thing you need to set in your curl options!!

Comment: RamRaider, if you put your comment as an answer I will accept it as it allowed me to move on. I was able to get to the point where I get a valid response, and am able to see the POST parameters filled in the login and password fields. However, at this point I'm stuck getting the form to submit; I tried adding the the Login button to the POST parameters, but since it doesn't have a "name=" I botching that part and the form is not submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier way to automate the download of the file would be to go to https://www.maxmind.com/en/download_files and copy the link URL for the database format you require. If you wish to always download the latest database, remove the date parameter from the URL. If you are using using wget or curl from a shell script, please be sure to put the URL within quotes.

If you are downloading the dat or mmdb formats, there is also a program to handle automatic updates, http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/

Comment: Unfortunately this will be deployed on Windows, so I can't utilize the automatic update provided by MaxMind. Downloading files from the link you provided is exactly what I'm trying to do, but it requires a login first.

Comment: I believe that the https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download itself doesn't require a login, since that link should have a license key embedded in the URL. Are you being asked for a login when you request https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download with the license key as one of the parameters?

Comment: Well, son of a ..., I had the download working with just the link a couple of weeks ago; came back to it yesterday and it wasn't working so I thought just needed authentication. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: The culprit turned out to be an extra parameter "date=" which is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to your statement above I'll add my comment in a re-hashed format with some additional code - however it seems you already found a solution and accepted an answer already but nevermind.

Generally a curl request to a SSL endpoint requires more options to be configured, notably in many instances the use of a valid `cacert.pem` file and explicit options for verifying the SSL host. The auth method chosen in the original code is more suited to logging into a restricted area protected by a `.htaccess` file rather than a standard web based login form where the fields used in the post request should follow the names given in the form elements. Generally when trying to emulate a web login I will copy the form in question and then find all the `input` elements and use them in the POST data I supply to the curl request.

```
/* A simple curl function */
function mmcurl( $url=NULL, $data=array(), $options=NULL ){

    /* Download cacert.pem and change path here to suit */
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
    $cookiejar=tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), '_cookiejar_' );                    


    $curl=curl_init();

    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
    }

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

    if( $options->cookie ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiejar );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejar );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookiejar );
    }
    if( $options->post ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $data ) );
    }

    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl ),
        'cookie'    =>  $cookiejar
    );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}




/* configure and call the function - used the suggestion from @Thomas for the endpoint url  */
$url='https://www.maxmind.com/en/download_files';
$data=array(
    'login'         =>  $username,  /* where $username & $password are YOUR variables */
    'password'      =>  $password,
    'pkit_login'    =>  1,
    'pkit_done'     =>  '/en/download_files',
    'Login'         =>  'Login'
);
$options=(object)array(
    'post'  =>true,
    'cookie'=>true
);

$res=mmcurl( $url, $data, $options );

pre($res->info);
```

Because I do not have an account I could not test further than this but using a dummy username/password the response was a `401` error which seems about right for the wrong username and password.